# How to know when the bottom of the text file has been reached

Tags: python, text-files

So I have a text file that has details of the users of my program.

In my program I have a login system which retrieves the data from this text file but I don't know how to tell when I have reached the end of it.

A sample of the data from the text file looks like this:

> Bob, Bob15, football, 15

My code for it looks like this:

```
username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")

file = open("userDetails.txt", "r")
match = False
while match == False:
    finished = False
    while finished == False:
        for each in file:
            each = each.split(", ")
            realUser = each[1]
            realPass = each[2]
            if realUser == username and realPass == password:
                match = True
                finished = True
                print("match")
            elif each == "":
                finished = False
                username = input("Re-enter username: ")
                password = input("Re-enter password: ")
                match = False
            else:
                finished = False
```

The part I am unsure about is the `elif each == "":` part.

Any ideas?

Comment: After the `for each in file:` loop, the file pointer is at the end of the file. No need to check from within the loop.

Comment: @schwobaseggl I don't really understand what you mean

Comment: The loop loops through all the lines in the files. Once the loop is finished, there ar no more lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the problem, I believe the use of [`for-else`](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/for_-_else.html#else-clause) clause would be ideal here.
**NOTE**: The `else` clause of the `for` loop is executed when the loop exits normally i.e no `break` statement is encountered.

**ALGORITHM**
 1. Ask the user for input
 2. Set flag `match` to be `False` initially
 3. Search in the file until a match is found.
 4. Open the file using a context manager; ensuring that the file is closed after operations.
 5. As soon as a match is found is found, break out of the file loop while setting the flag `match` as `True`.
 6. If no match is found, ask the user to reenter the credentials and perform the search operation yet again.
 7. Continue till a match is found.

**CODE**

```
username = input("Enter username: ")
password = input("Enter password: ")

match = False
while not match:
    with open("userDetails.txt", "r") as file:
        for line in file:
            user_data = line.split(",")
            real_user, real_pass = user_data[1].strip(), user_data[2].strip()
            if username == real_user and password == real_pass
                print('Match')
                match = True
                break
        else:
            username = input("Re-enter username: ")
            password = input("Re-enter password: ")
```

**TIP**: You can also give the CSV Module a try for reading the data file in Python.

Answer (score 0):

When the end of the file is reached for cycle ends, the correct code is:

```
file = open("userDetails.txt", "r")
match = False
while match == False:
    for each in file:
        each = each.split(", ")
        realUser = each[1]
        realPass = each[2]
        if realUser == username and realPass == password:
            match = True
            print("match")
        elif each == "":
            username = input("Re-enter username: ")
            password = input("Re-enter password: ")
            match = False
```